# Format date in dd mm yyyy where month is shortened word like Apr

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the date today to a specific format

Hoping to achieve the format (dd mm yyyy) and the month is the ***shortened version*** in string format:

```
03 Apr 2022
```

I tried to do the following:

```
const dateToday = new Date()

const options = {
    year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'
}

console.log(dateToday.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options))
```

The output I get is

```
Apr 3, 2022
```

Any recommendations I can take?

Comment: Please try this: `console.log(\`${dateToday.toLocaleDateString({}, { day: '2-digit' })}-${dateToday.toLocaleDateString({}, { month: 'short' })}-${dateToday.toLocaleDateString({}, { year: 'numeric' })}\`);`

Comment: With a little modification, I got the answer I needed. Thanks for this.